# Move iFrame in the DOM using jQuery

Tags: jquery, tinymce

My overall aim is to create an editor which I can skin using jQuery UI (by creating a custom toolbar which uses integration calls), using TinyMCE.

Lets say I have a TinyMCE editor on a page. The actual editor is an iFrame contained inside a lot of horrible table code, which is also where the current (to be scrapped) toolbar is. I want just the iframe inside a div - ideally get rid of the table code.

So...I want to transform:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><iframe id="xyz"></iframe></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

into

```
<div id="test">
    <iframe id="xyz"></iframe>
</div>
```

So far, I've tried using:

```
$('#xyz').clone(true).appendTo('#test');
```

Which clones the iframe, but no content inside it.

Is there a way to make this work?

If not, can I somehow strip the table code from around the iFrame away?

If I cant do that, I'll think I'll have to keep the table code.

Comment: Something strange going on here... I can use artlung's suggestion, but the iframe contents are then emptied. 

Also, CodeJousts suggestion is replacing the table with nothing... Seems that the iframe is reporting itself as empty?

Comment: I've put the code im using on pastebin... http://pastebin.com/8CQ5GBd6

Its the code in the click function starting at line 30.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Couldn't get this working properly, so instead got rid of the TinyMCE UI with a bit of CSS.

Thanks for all the suggestions though!

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
// http://api.jquery.com/replaceWith/
$('table:has(#xyz)').replaceWith($('#xyz'));
// http://api.jquery.com/wrap/
$('#xyz').wrap('<div id="test" />');
```

Comment: Kind of the same as what the code I tried was doing...its moving the iFrame ok, but not the content inside it - firebug just shows empty head and body tags.

Comment: It may matter what's in there, and when it gets loaded. You may need to reload the content into your `iframe`.

Answer (score 1):

you have to save iframe's html node somewhere (e.g. iframe itself), then restore this node after iframe moving:

```
iframe.htmlNode = iframe.contentDocument.getElementsByTagName('html')[0];
// moving iframe here ......

// restoring html node
var html = iframe.contentDocument.documentElement;
html.parentNode.removeChild(html);
iframe.contentDocument.appendChild(iframe.htmlNode);
```

The code may be optimized a lot, but the main idea remains the same.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('table').replaceWith($('iframe:first'));
```

Try that... It replaces the table with the inner iframe.