# jQuery move youtube video while it's playing

Tags: jquery, html, youtube

I have a container in which youtube is playing video.

`<div id="current-container"><span class="youtube"></span></div>`

And I have another `#new-container` in which I want to move it after some event.

this is how I'm doing it:

`jQuery('#new-container').html(jQuery('#current-container').find('span.youtube'))`

the problem with it is that it stops playing and kind of makes new iframe.

I also tried `clone()` with span and iframe as well

here is a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3SGUL/)

any solution will do, even when keeping current video in its own container and just making copy. nothing worked so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you write :

```
jQuery('#new-container').html(...)
```

jQuery rebuild a entire content as string, then put it inside your 'new-container' to recreate a Object inside.

The [.append()](http://api.jquery.com/append/) method should work but not on iframe, as said  here : [moving iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8318264/how-to-move-an-iframe-in-the-dom-without-losing-its-state) .

Maybe a good try is to put your 'current-container' in a fixed positionning, and place it at the exact position of the new-container. Something like this in jquery :

```
$('#current-container').css('position','fixed')
                       .offset($('#new-container').offset());
```

The [.offset()](http://api.jquery.com/offset/) change the position of your object but the DOM  structure don't change. You can also change the size of current-container to fit the new-container size.

Hope this trick help !

Comment: sadly it does not work, but good point about reconstruction. I'll try to dig deeper

Comment: ok, after googling, it's not possible to move iframe in the DOM without reloading. But let me edit with a trick

Comment: I guess this will be responsive solution, so I'll go with it

Comment: if you scroll or if you resize the windows, you will probably have to refresh the positionning