# JS to move iframe inside another div without refreshing its contents

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe

I would like to move the iframe from d1 to d2, without having its contents refreshed.

```
<div id="d1"> 
<iframe src="http://www.website.com/"></iframe>
<div id="d2"></div>
</div>
```

I have tried the `getElementById()` with `appendChild()` but it ends up deleting everything.

Comment: Even if you use `.innerHTML`, `.appendChild()`, or JQuery's [.before](http://api.jquery.com/before/) it'll add a new iframe instance and thus your contents would be removed.  Nice question! I never thought of this and would like to see a solution.

Comment: This might be of a help to you - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8318264/how-to-move-an-iframe-in-the-dom-without-losing-its-state