# Loading another site without delay and positioning it correctly using CSS?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, internet-explorer-11

I have an `angularjs` web application that loads another site within an `iframe` in a specified `div`. Internet Explorer 11 loads the `angularjs` + `requirejs` so slowly, that I need to wait for around 4 seconds **till** the other site's loading is **triggered** (iframe's `src` injected into the `dom`).

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div ng-app="module">
      <!-- happens after 3-4 seconds due to the delay mentioned above-->
      <div id="otherapp">
        <iframe src="https://www.bing.com">
        Another Site
        </iframe>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I would like to parallelize this by going something like this instead:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div id="othersite">
      <!-- loads immediately -->
      <iframe src="https://www.bing.com">
      Other Site
      </iframe>
    </div>
    <div ng-app="module">
      <!-- bring it here either using dom manipulation or css -->
      <div id="othersiteholder">
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Since there is an `iframe`, I [can't](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8318264/how-to-move-an-iframe-in-the-dom-without-losing-its-state/) move the `div` element using `appendChild`. Is there a CSS solution that can be used here as it a positioning problem? Something like:

1. Create the `otherapp` `div` with an `absolute` position.
2. The application will create an `otherappholder` `div` and leaves some position for this page.
3. It calculates it offset and repositions the `otherapp` `div`.

While this is for an `angularjs` application, I am looking for a pure CSS based solution for this problem using `position: absolute`, `position: relative` etc.

Comment: You should add a container div for both your angular app and the iframe container. Set the container to `position: relative` and the iframe to `postiion: absolute`. Then, you'll need to position `div#othersite` into `div#othersiteholder`. Using a fixed height would be easiest, but you might be able to use `height: 100%`. Not really clear though, an image or example of what you are trying to achieve would really help.

Comment: Thanks, @ChaseDeAnda. You understood it correctly. That is a nice approach. I am trying to apply this idea!