# How do I do some action after ng-if, ng-show etc happens in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am working on a [workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50448792/loading-another-site-without-delay-and-positioning-it-correctly-using-css) using `position: absolute` that needs the position of a `div` to be calculated.

```
<html>
  <!-- this iframe will positioned by an angular partial through a directive -->
  <iframe style="position: absolute; width: 400px; height: 400px";></iframe>
  <div id="angular"></div>
<html>
```

It works fine for static partials like this:

```
<div id="dummy" style="width: 400px; height: 400px;"></div>
<reposition></reposition>
```

but for dynamic partials that have `ng-if` or `ng-show` it won't work because the calculated positions will change after rendering.

```
<div ng-if="variable" style="width: 200px; height: 200px"></div>
<div id="dummy" style="width: 400px; height: 400px;"></div>
<reposition></reposition>
```

If I can intercept `ng-if` and `ng-show` to do the following: `ng-if`, `code to reposition` then I can make it work. I was thinking about writing a new directive say `ng-hack-if` that would do the same.

Here is the [codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/jxjmrR?editors=1010#0). Just toggle the directive's `ng-show` from `true` to `false`. When it is `true` everything works, `reposition` works fine. But when it is `false`, `reposition` thinks there is a `div` but Angular removes it in its the evaluation cycle. I simply need to call the `moveContainerAccordingToHolder` when AngularJS does a DOM modification i.e calls `ng-show` in this case.

Comment: Can you post some code as well, that would be more helpful?

Comment: Sorry, didn't give the context earlier @VicJordan. I just updated the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can delay the executing of the function until DOM has finished rendering by using the **setTimeOut** function.

```
module1.directive('reposition', [function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            var holder = angular.element(
                document.getElementById("holder")
            )[0];
            setTimeout(function() {
              window.moveContainerAccordingToHolder(holder);
            },0);
        },
        template: directiveTemplate
    };
}]);
```

This works for ng-show="false" as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can try with the `ngStyle` directive of `AngularJS`. It helps you to dynamically change the CSS of any element. Check this [link](https://www.concretepage.com/angular-2/angular-2-ngstyle-and-style-binding-example).

Comment: `ngStyle` is a good direction to think though I don't know if it solves manual DOM manipulation problems.

Answer (score 1):

Please check this answer,

I made a toggle function and made a `variable` `show` to display and hide the `div` and I called `moveContainerAccordingToHolder` inside that function.

I added a `click to toggle` button, please click that `button`

**Here is your directive:**

```
    directiveTemplate = `
    <div id="directive">
        <span ng-click="toggleShow()"> Click to Toggle </span>
        <div id="pre" style="width: 102.4px; height: 35.9px" ng-show="show">
            Pre
        </div>
        <div id="holder" style="width: 102.4px; height: 76.8px; border:1pt dashed gray;">
        </div>
        <div id="post" width="102.4">
            Post
        </div>
    </div>`;

    // Integration Begins

    function moveContainerAccordingToHolder(holder) {
        var reposition = document.getElementById('reposition');
        reposition.style.border = "1pt solid green";
        reposition.style.position = "absolute";
        var holderTop = holder.getBoundingClientRect().top;
        var holderLeft = holder.getBoundingClientRect().left;
        var scrollTop = document.documentElement.scrollTop;
        var scrollLeft = document.documentElement.scrollLeft;
        holderTop = holderTop + scrollTop + 1;
        holderLeft = holderLeft + scrollLeft + 1;
        holderTop = String(holderTop) + "px";
        holderLeft = String(holderLeft) + "px";
        reposition.style.top = holderTop;
        reposition.style.left = holderLeft;
        reposition.style.display = "block";
    }

    // Integration Ends

    // Angular Begins

    (function(angular) {
        'use strict';
        var module1 = angular.module('module', []);
        module1.controller('Controller', ['$scope', function($scope) {

        }]);
        module1.directive('reposition', [function() {
            return {
                restrict: 'E',
                replace: true,
                link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
                    scope.show = true;
                    var holder = angular.element(
                        document.getElementById("holder")
                    )[0];
                    window.moveContainerAccordingToHolder(holder);
                    scope.toggleShow = function(){
                      scope.show = !scope.show
                      window.moveContainerAccordingToHolder(holder);

                    }
                },
                template: directiveTemplate
            };
        }]);
    })(window.angular);

// Angular Ends
```

[**Here is a DEMO for the same**](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/rvEwyY?editors=1010)

Comment: It should happen automatically since I can't make the user click :-)

Answer (score 0):

Do it in a directive way. And from the directive you will create, put the logic there.

Answer (score 0):

The option of [over-riding](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/bMXgad?editors=1011) the directive's parent's `$scope.$apply` and `$scope.$digest` from within the directive's `link` function is also nice. This way, any change to the partial would trigger the repositioning which is what I wanted.

```
var parentApply = scope.$parent.$apply;
var parentDigest = scope.$parent.$digest;
scope.$parent.$apply = function() {
    console.log("Apply was called");
    var r = parentApply.call(scope.$parent);
    moveContainerAccordingToHolder(holder);
    return r;
};
scope.$parent.$digest = function() {
    console.log("Digest was called");
    var r = parentDigest.call(scope.$parent);
    moveContainerAccordingToHolder(holder);
    return r;
};
```