# How can I move an <iframe> element without reloading it?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I have a description list whose `<dd>` elements may include `<iframe>` elements, and the page offers an option to sort the list in various ways. My vanilla js sort routine uses `Element.after()` and `Element.before()` to move stuff around in the list when a sort option is selected, and that's working fine. But I see from the browser dev tools that anytime a `<dd>` containing an `<iframe>` is moved by being mentioned as the argument of `Element.before()` or `Element.after()` then it's `<iframe>` is reloaded from its src attribute.

I don't want this to happen. I don't want a refresh of the `<iframe>`, but the data already in it should just move into place along with its containing `<dd>`. I see during the sort that as an `<iframe>` gets pushed around in the list as a result of other elements moving then there's no problem. It's only when a `<dd>` with an `<iframe>` is the target of `Element.before()` or `Element.after()` that I see the unwanted refresh.

In practice it's not a big performance hit because a local result cache ends up serving the `<iframe>` refresh, and so there's no Internet access triggered, but I want to get rid of these unwanted refreshes.

Comment: Can you clarify if you have to change the tree or all you need is a visual sort?

Comment: Are you sure it's moving the element, not reasssigning the `innerHTML`?

Comment: Please post a [mre] that shows how the elements are being moved.

Comment: @MattMiller I'd go for sort elements in an array to find order and than position:absolute according to index (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Positioning). I don't think I will have time to write complete answer (so providing this roadmap in the comment) - so feel free to self-answer if you get it working.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8318264/how-to-move-an-iframe-in-the-dom-without-losing-its-state

Comment: A working prototype that uses shadow DOM and slotting: https://github.com/whatwg/html/issues/5484#issuecomment-620481794